# URL in razor pages dosen't send data to another page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, jquery-ajaxq

I'm using Razor Pages and I have two pages `CreateModel` and `EditModel`, in CreateModel there is `OnGetSubGroups` handler:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel    
 {
  //Dependency Injection is here

  public IActionResult OnGetSubGroups(int subId)
  {
   SubOptions = courseService.CourseSubGroups(subId);
   return new JsonResult(SubOptions);
   }
 }
```

now the problem is when i want to pass data using JQuery Ajax in Edit.cshtml  to `OnGetSubGroups` URL doesn't work:

```
$('#Course_GroupId').on('change', function (e) {
 var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
 var valueSelected = this.value;
 $.ajax({
   type: "Get",                
    data: {
    subId: valueSelected,                                           
    },          
    url: "/Create?handler=SubGroups",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

i've used breakpoint and url dosen't work. where is the problem?

Comment: The url you are calling with ajax is a client side and to be used from client side need to be replaced.

Comment: I've searched every post on this site all was same as I've written on top.

Comment: I mean the `url: "/Create?handler=SubGroups".replace('[your action]', [your action])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For routing from `Edit` to `Create`, you could not use the URL `"/Create?handler=SubGroups"` which will generate URL like `https://localhost:44389/Create?handler=SubGroups&subId=5` and ignore the `PageFolder`. I assume `CreateModel` is not in the root folder `Pages`. If so, you should not combine URL with `"/Create?handler=SubGroups"`.

I suggest you try code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            data: {
                subId: 5,
            },
            url:"@Url.Page("Create", "SubGroups")",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is check if the AJAX request is even being made. You can do that in Chrome and IE/Edge by hitting F12 to bring up the developer tools and looking at the network tab when you change the value in the element (Select list?) with the ID of `Course_GroupId`. If no request is made, then you may have the `change` event handler wired up to the wrong element or an element that doesn't exist. If  request is made, examine its URL and the response.